# How should I be migrating CoreData documents within the app sandbox?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, data-migration

I am trying to update my CoreData based application to meet the requirements for running in a  Sandbox. However, migrations are proving difficult. It seems NSPersistentDocument tries to do migrations in-place and wants to save to disk without the user's permission. Because of this, lightweight migrations fail.

I can only imagine that someone I need to avoid doing the migration on disk, but I can't figure out how to do this in NSPersistentDocument. It has been suggested to subclass NSDocumentController and override makeDocumentForURL:... to check whether migrations are required. I assume that the logic at that point would be to create a new untitled document and migrate the data to that, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach or what other approaches should be considered.

How should I perform migrations for sandboxed core data applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the solution was more complex than I imagined. Because there is a lot of code I wrote the answer on my journal: http://www.codeotaku.com/blog/2012-06/sandboxing-core-data-and-migrations

However, here is a brief summary: Core Data tries to migrate the data and write to the file in -place. This doesn't work in the sandbox because you only have read-only access to the file. So, Core Data migration fails. In my case, I hijacked the document creation process to check if migration is required, and if so, ask the user (by presenting an NSSavePanel) to choose a location for the migrated data. Then, the migration task is passed off to a specialised class with does the migration in a suitable temporary directory. The final data is copied back out to the location that the user specified and then that document is opened instead.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around it with temporary entitlements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write</key>
    <string>/Volumes/</string>
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write</key>
    <string>/</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

That got automatic migration working as it did without sandbox enabled.

However, it is essentially disabling a large portion of the sandbox, so I'm not sure how apple will react when it comes time for app store approval.

On developer.apple.com, they recommend submitting a bug when you find yourself having to use temporary entitlements.

Comment: I had a similar problem in a non-document app: for 2 days I just couldn't import an old database. I switched off sandboxing (the migration worked) and then turned on the sandboxing again and went through the entitlements in the Target Summary screen in Xcode 4 making sure I had read/write access. And hey-bloody presto it all-bloody-well worked! I didn't need the temporary entitlements described above. I'm not saying you're wrong, PTG, but just in case the refreshing of the .entitlements file comes in useful for someone...